# Cannot install sp_blitzfirst on sql azure db

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sp-blitzfirst

I'm trying to install Brent Ozar's `SP_BlitzFirst` on a user database on an Azure SQL Database instance.

However, I get the error:

> The module 'sp_BlitzFirst' depends on the missing object 'sp_MSforeachdb'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists."

I have a nasty feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but I don't really know where to go from here... Can anyone advise please?

I downloaded it today from https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/ so I'm assuming it's the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the readme](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main) states:

> Azure SQL DB - not supported. Some of the procedures work, but some
> don't, and Microsoft has a tendency to change DMVs in Azure without
> warning, so we don't put any effort into supporting it. If it works,
> great! If not, any changes to make it work would be on you. See the
> contributing.md file for how to do that.

Comment: Ah. Yes, thanks. I missed that amid my excitement that most versions of SQL Server since Noah built an ark are supported...

Comment: @Brent Ozar That is an uncomfortable place to be in: finding out my trusty tools have been confiscated for the sake of progress. Sigh.